# AngularJS $state does not change view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my AngularJS application in run() function I want to send user to signin page if they are not logged in. Here is code:

```
.run(['$state', function($state)
{
    $state.go('signin')
        .then(function(promise){},
            function(reject)
            {
                console.log(reject)
            }
        );
}]);
```

In console I get following:

```
Error: transition superseded {stack: (...), message: "transition superseded"}
```

Neither `$state.transitionTo('signin')` doesn't work. Does anyone have idea why this happens, I've never encountered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be checking for authentication in the `$stateProvider` instead of `run()`. You could do something like this instead:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('auth', {
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
      user: ['auth', '$q', function (auth, $q) {

        if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          //...
        } else {
          //...
        }

      }]
    }
  })
```

Comment: I agree, makes more sense.I usually do mine with a $watch in my base controller

Comment: Thanks, I used your example and then I just listen in run() function on $stateChangeError and then i change view to signin.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that the state is still not loaded so you cant go to that state...

a solution would be to set timeout 0 so it runs this after the stack is empty.

try this:

```
.run($timeout, $state, ...) {

$timeout(function() {
    $state.go('signin');
},0);
```

or something like that

referanced from :

> [module.run() and $state.go() angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355213/module-run-and-state-go-angularjs)